# PAS-Windows: how can container talk to a process on the VM?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Pivotal Application Service for Windows is fairly new.  I've created a bosh addon that runs on each VM.  I need for it to open a port, a named pipe, a shared file (or something) in such a way that programs in containers can communicate with the process on their host VM. Currently, ports, pipes, and file systems are blocked via container isolation.

This is only an issue with Pivotal's PAS for Windows, where addons run as Microsoft services.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but I don't think this is an issue or problem. It sounds very much like it's working as designed. The containers are doing what they are supposed to do and isolating the workloads. Rather than try to punch holes in that and potentially create security issues, you might need to look at architecting what you are trying to do in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Pivotal, I need to create an ASG (Application Security Group), using an errand in our Tile.  That way, I can open a port from the container to talk to a port on the host that our bosh addon is listening to.